# Why is the movie "Event Horizon" called that?

Tags: title, event-horizon

In astrophysics, an event horizon is a boundary beyond which events cannot affect an observer. But what does that have to do with the movie?

Comment: I'd like to invite you to the [SciFiStackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-horizon), that has quite a few questions about this movie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the name of the spaceship they go to rescue.

The *Event Horizon* was built with a gravity drive, designed to generate an artificial black hole and use it to bridge two points in space, thereby reducing travel time over large distances.

To enter a black hole, one passes the event horizon.